# Why no internet connection with pfsense behind modem in bridge mode?

Tags: networking, router, modem, gateway, pfsense

I have successfully put my modem in bridge mode so that i can now reach my pfsense in the browser via the static IP provided by my ISP.

The problem i am facing now is no internet connection.

These are the settings i pulled from my modem before putting it in bridge mode:

[image]

I gave the WAN interface on pfsense the static IP from ISP. When entering the default gateway address as seen in the image (10.xx.255.x17), i got "not in subnet" message. After i enabled the advanced option "Use non-local gateway", it accepted the gateway address but i had no internet connection.

**What am i doing wrong here?**

Comment: How would you imagine this is going to work? How are you expecting this machine to reach its default gateway?

Answer (score 0):

You would only use a non-local gateway under very unusual circumstances. For example, if you had more than one local path to the same machine or had a default gateway with a VRRP address. You are not in any such unusual circumstances, so you should set the default gateway to something local.

IP routes on a hop by hop basis. Each device needs to know an appropriate next hop for every destination it might want to reach. But, in normal circumstances, it does not need to know or care what happens after that. So if you have no local device that will work as a default gateway, you cannot reach the Internet. You can only reach a device that's not local through some device that is local. So your default gateway should be the IP address of that local device.

Comment: So if my modems local IP is 192.168.1.1 (factory default), i should use that for my WAN gateway on pfsense? Apologies for my noobishness!

Comment: If your modem is bridged, then it's invisible at the IP level. From the point of view of IP, your router is directly connected to some other router (through the lower layer bridge). That other router is your default gateway and from IP's point of view, you are directly connected to it. So your router's default gateway will be the IP address of that other router, typically specifically the one assigned to the interface you are connected to. In most cases, this is set up automatically by DHCP.

Comment: Oh god.. it still sound like a foreign language to me. I am sorry! Can you please have a look at my previous post that i deleted cause i thought i managed to do it right [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1249463/correct-settings-for-modem-bridge-mode-for-pfsense-wan-with-static-ip). Should i not set a WAN IP nor Gateway address in pfsense?

Comment: The normal, default connections for Internet access should work.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try at office in the morning and report back.

Comment: After talking with technical support of ISP, i used PPPoE connection in pfsense. This seemed to be the only way to have in and outgoing traffic. Does this give me the same possibilities that i would have using static IP as WAN address and ISP gateway as WAN gateway? Or are there any disadvantages doing PPPoE?

Comment: If your ISP says your connection to them uses PPPoE, then that's what you should use. It acts like an IP tunnel that makes your router act like it's directly connected to whatever device the ISP has that handles your Internet traffic.